# Is it possible to delete selection using mouse in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, text-editors, text-editing

Like we can select part of text and then copy/cut/paste using Edit menu or Right Click context menu. Is it possible to delete selected text similar way in visual studio code?

Please do not suggest keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Hmm. "cut" will delete the text ...

Comment: I use that. But when i do need to copy paste a lot, it slows me down.

Comment: Do you mean that you selected text to automatically be copied to the clipboard? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: Related on SO: [How to customize context menu in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46714353/11107541). What are you even looking for? The typical mouse only has three buttons. Do you want an answer that involves the context menu or no?